# How can I transfer "foreach loop" to "for loop" in PHP Laravel 7.3.x

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

This bloc code in my website is displaying products for a category, but the problem is that it's display all the products, so I want to convert it to "for loop" like this as I know C# `for(int i = 0; i <= 12; i++){//Todo}`

```
@foreach($trending_categories as $trending_category)
<div class="tab-pane fade {{ $loop->first ? 'show active' : '' }}" id="trending_category{{ $trending_category->id }}" role="tabpanel">
    <div class="tab-single">
        <div class="row">
            @php $products = $trending_category->products; @endphp
            @include('theme.default.components.product-grid',['class' => 'col-xl-3'])
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Thanks for Help in advance.

Comment: It works the same as you know it from C#. What seems to be the thing that's blocking you from converting it? You showed the loop you're attempting to convert into a for loop, but you don't actually present any for loop to indicate what you've tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you check the documentation first? `@for` is exactly the same.

Comment: With that said, you could just sort through your associative array to display what you want if you need some filtering, e.g. not display every category and then run it through the foreach instead, or better yet, fix the problem at the level of the query itself. This would also be a more optimal approach.

Answer (score 1):

```php
@for($i=0;$i<count($trending_categories);$i++)
@php $trending_category = $trending_categories[$i]; @endphp
<div class="tab-pane fade {{ $loop->first ? 'show active' : '' }}" id="trending_category{{ $trending_category->id }}" role="tabpanel">
    <div class="tab-single">
        <div class="row">
            @php $products = $trending_category->products; @endphp
            @include('theme.default.components.product-grid',['class' => 'col-xl-3'])
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endfor
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: You'd probably need to do (at)endfor instead of (at)endforeach.

Comment: @Martin Thank you